# Jsoup doc.select - как определить первое слово

Tags: java, jsoup

Нужно из #mrp получить число 1.01, что-то типа

> Element mrp = doc.select("#mrp").firstword();

```
<div id="mrp">1.01 - 2.4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартных способов это сделать нет, т.к. нет однозначно верного способа получения "слова" для всех возможных языков и случаев. Придётся решать иначе - регулярками или разбиением строк. Советую второй вариант - разбиваем строку по пробелу и берём первый элемент полученного массива:

```
String firstWord = doc.select("#mrp").text().split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: Очень хороший совет, спасибо